# No TeX installation detected. Please install TeX before compiling - RStudio Knitr on Mac

Tags: installing, compiling, mactex, knitr, rstudio

I have tried to reinstall the MacTex twice. I even reinstall R and RStudio. Nothing could cure this problem. Please Help me, I'm in middle of my thesis and I need to use Knitr and RStudio is only easy and suitable place for me to work in.

The output for

```
which pdflatex
echo $PATH
```

are:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex
/Users/therimalaya/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

respectively

Comment: Please post your R version and RStudio version, and please upgrade them to their latest versions, respectively, if you have not done so.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: how exactly are you starting `Rstudio`? Commandline or menu/icon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns a bug in a beta version of Mac OS X and is unrelated to (La)TeX and friends.

Comment: I would also like to note that during the "middle of one's thesis" is probably not the best time to be testing an experimental operating system. :-)

Answer (score 1):

R, rstudio and latex all are in there latest version. I think the problem is in OS X yesomite beta. I downgrade the system. It is working fine now.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Yosemite beta has a significant bug in passing environment variables to subprocesses (duplicate/incorrect PATH, for instance).